# How to remove the duplicates elements in an array without using any built in array methods using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As per the title, in one of the interview I got the above problem to solve, but i confused to get the answer. Can any one give me the solution please.

Thanks in Advance!

I am expecting solution as per the requirement without using any built in methods available in JavaScript.

Comment: please add your try. what goes wrong?

Comment: Does `Array.isArray` qualify for an array-method? Though it's a static method, it's more like a function nailed to the `Array` namespace.

Comment: What's considered "a built-in array method"? What about `[...new Set(origArray)]`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can remove duplicate elements from an array in JavaScript without using built-in array methods by creating a new array and iterating through the original array. Here's one way to achieve this:

```js
let removeDuplicates=(arr)=> {
  let uniqueArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (uniqueArray.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1) {
      uniqueArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return uniqueArray;
}

// Example usage:
const originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5];
const newArray = removeDuplicates(originalArray);

console.log(newArray); // Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In the above example, the removeDuplicates function iterates through the original array (arr) and checks whether each element is already present in the uniqueArray using the indexOf method. If the element is not found in uniqueArray (i.e., indexOf returns -1), it is added to the uniqueArray. This way, duplicates are not included in the new array.

Comment: Thanks for the Solution. I got concept now.  Your explanation helped more to get clarity on the task. Thanks a lot

Comment: The `indexOf` approach does only cover values which are strictly comparable, hence references, the `undefined` and the `null` value as well as primitive values like `boolean`, `number` and `string`. It fails at `-0` versus `0`, at comparing `Number.NaN` against itself and at comparing unique data-objects which are structurally equal.

Comment: @Babu ... And of cause `indexOf` and `push` are array methods, thus the OP either does not accept this answer or does change the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a for loop.

The `removeDuplicates` function takes an array as input and creates a new array (`uniqueArray`) to store the unique elements. It then iterates through each element in the input array using a for loop.

For each element in the input array, it checks whether that element is already present in the `uniqueArray` using the `indexOf` method. If the element is not found (i.e., indexOf returns -1), it means the element is unique, and it is added to the uniqueArray using the `push` method.

See below example:

```
function removeDuplicates(array) {
  var uniqueArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (uniqueArray.indexOf(array[i]) === -1) {
      uniqueArray.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return uniqueArray;
}

var originalArray = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5];
var newArray = removeDuplicates(originalArray);

console.log(newArray); // Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```